The smallest nontrivial zero of the Riemann zeta function
Consider the Riemann zeta function $$\zeta(s)=\dfrac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s},\operatorname {R}(s)>0.$$ Riemann suggested that all nontrivial zeroes lie on the line $\operatorname{R}(s)=1/2$. What is the simplest way to prove that

There is at least one nontrivial zero?

The real part of the nontrivial zero closest to the origin is equal to $1/2$?

How to estimate the imaginary part of the zero closest to the origin?



Does that zeros are isolated imply there must be a non-real zero? What about $f(z)=1/z$?

Have a look at this (we can use numerical evaluation to prove things about the first zeroes of $\zeta$). But of course we know a lot more, for instance we know how many zeroes there are in the critical strip up to height $T$.

For a discussion relevant to 1, see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13647/why-does-the-riemann-zeta-function-have-non-trivial-zeros

I think simplest is the operative word here.

I suggest reading Edward's book "The Riemann Zeta Function" which has a fair bit about all three of these questions. The book has a few idiosyncrasies (There is a weird notational choice of using a gamma function moved over by 1 to match factorials, and there's a strange lack of discussion of L functions) but it is a good place to go.

A sum of exponentials always has a nonreal zero when it converges in the positive direction. This is because the dominant exponential parts of the function change and where it does you get zero's.
See : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351157/why-does-sum-a-i-expb-i-always-have-root
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793875/why-do-dirichlet-series-always-have-infinitely-many-nontrivial-nonreal-zeros
Maybe that helps.

For Q3: A brief, perhaps simple, argument for why the smallest nontrivial zero with real part 1/2 has imaginary part in the interval (14.1,14.2) is on page 157 of Edwards' book mentioned by JoshuaZ – you can access it here. The calculation uses the Hardy function, a real function that changes sign at the zeta roots on the critical line (see plot from MathWorld) and which can be computed efficiently.
This calculation of course also answers Q1 (that there is at least one nontrivial zero).


It might be added that the current best result in this direction seems to be that RH has been established for imaginary part up to $3\cdot10^{12}$ (Platt & Trudgian, BLMS 2021)

For Q2 and Q3, see the first two pages of Chapter XV in Titchmarsh's book ("The theory of the Riemann zeta-function", 2nd edition). Titchmarsh shows that:

Between height 0 and $6 \pi$ there is at least one zero on the critical line,
The total number of zeros  of $\zeta$ between height $0$ and $6\pi$ is less than $2$, i.e., at most $1$. (Since the number of zeros is an integer...)

Thus, there is exactly one zero up to height $6\pi$ and it must lie on the critical line.
The rest of that short chapter discusses refinements and extensions of this.
Step 1 uses the Hardy Z-function mentioned in Carlo Beenakker's answer, which detects zeros on the critical line, while Step 2 uses the argument principle.
Q1, as mentioned in the comments by Mark Lewko, was asked by Gowers and answered by Lucia previously.

Together with Carlo's answer, maybe this helps :
A sum of exponentials always has a nonreal zero when it converges in the positive direction. This is because the dominant exponential parts of the function change and where it does you get zero's.
See : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351157/why-does-sum-a-i-expb-i-always-have-root
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793875/why-do-dirichlet-series-always-have-infinitely-many-nontrivial-nonreal-zeros
